How do Nuxt Published modules import helper functions from a previously imported published module?
How do "published" modules import helper functions from a previously imported published module?
The docs say:

Published modules cannot leverage auto-imports for assets within their runtime directory. Instead, they have to import them explicitly from #imports or alike.


link to nuxt module docs
My attempts to import the helper I need from the previous package a nitro alias or from my build files have resulted in

WARN Duplicated imports
ERROR Vue app aliases are not allowed at runtime
ERROR RollupError

Issue: https://github.com/Atinux/nuxt-auth-utils/issues/110

What are your attempts exactly? Here it talks about being explicit regarding the imports.

I have attempted to import from the original package, the nitro imports with the alias and with my own stubbed helper file.
Code specifics are available here
